# The bevel tool isn't applying to the front view edge

Tags: bevel

I'm trying to curve the edge of the plane, however when I apply bevel it only curves the bottom of the plane and not the top. I've provided images on how I select my edge and the results I get even with the correct edge selection.
[image: Edge selection]

[image: After Bevel applied - Front view]

[image: After Bevel applied - Back view]

[image: After Bevel applied - Side view]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your object?

Comment: Sure thing, I've just included the file.

Comment: thanks but you should share the version before you bevel, but it looks like you have overlapping vertices, maybe select all and M > Merge by Distance before bevelling?

Comment: Thank you it worked. Could you kindly let me know how you knew my vertices were overlapping? Just want to learn this incase of next time.

Answer (score 3):

As moonboots has offered in comments, your bevel operation isn't acting like you'd like because you have doubled vertices.

You've asked in comments how to know that you have doubled vertices.  Experienced users know that they don't have doubled vertices because they haven't made any doubled vertices, and they're experienced enough to know what they've made.  But doubled vertices are a common problem for people starting out with Blender because they escape out of an extrude.  After a while, you just start to realize that if you extrude but don't want it, you should undo rather than escape out.  The escape cancels the grab part of an extrusion, but not the other parts of the extrusion operation.  (And, it's good that extrusion acts this way.  I escape out of about half of my extrusions, so I can scale the extruded edges instead of moving them along normals.)

But plenty of us troubleshoot other people's models on BSE or elsewhere.  I first suspect doubled vertices because operations act in certain ways that don't make sense unless there are doubled vertices.  In order to check this suspicion, I'll maybe just grab a vertex and move it:

[image]

When I select that vertex and grab it-- this pic is in the middle of a grab-- I can immediately see that there's another vertex underneath, in the exact same location.